# datagridview combobox column event raising

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a datagridview and two comobobox column inside the datagrid view in my form. Can any one suggest me what event sholud be raised for selecting an item from the second combobox column of the second row. i used a code but it is raising for each combobox column in each row

Comment: what is the version of ASP.NET do you use ? Do you use Telerik or ASP.NET controls ?

Comment: my data grid is in the windows application.

Comment: [Cell event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650271/itemdatabound-for-a-windows-forms-datagridview). You could check this to handle cell events